# How to choose between fixed-effects and random-effects model in meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis

In meta-analysis packages, both fixed effects and random effects models are available. How do one choose between these two models? Since one is assessing different studies, should one not choose random effects model all the time?

Comment: See also this follow-up question with a good answer providing literature review: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324221.